# The value of the JSON array displays undefiend after converting it into string

Tags: javascript, json, angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

Part of my service.spec.ts is below:

**service.spec.ts**

```
it('should mock the http requests', inject([Service, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {
    let result:any;
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({

           body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse),

        })));
    });
    service.getGoogle().subscribe((heroes: any) => {
        result = heroes;
        console.log('1', result);
        console.log('2', result[0]); //Logs shows this as undefined!!I need to print here "aditya"
               });     
}))
```

The value of **mockResponse** is as follows:

const mockResponse = [{"name":"aditya"},{"name":"xyz"}];

Logs:

```
LOG: 'Inside service'
LOG: '1', Response{_body: '[{"name":"aditya"},{"name":"xyz"}]', status: null, ok: false, statusText: null, headers: null, type: null, url: null}
LOG: '2', undefined
  Other method
    √ should mock the http requests
```

Note: `'[{"name":"aditya"},{"name":"xyz"}]'` This is a string! As I have converted it into `JSON.stringify(mockResponse)`, If I would have not used this then it displays as `Object: [....], Object: [....]`.

Comment: I am following this https://angular.io/api/http/ResponseOptions  Here it is using `body` but when in the Response its `_body`.Does it affect?

Comment: According to (1) `result` is not an array, but a response object, which has a `_body`-property, which has a JSON string. So (2) should be: `JSON.parseJSON(result._body)[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your question is. The code seems to be doing what you are asking.

This:

```
JSON.stringify(mockResponse),
```

Turns an array into a string. You are then making that string the value of an object with a key `body`. And returning it.

Your subscribe method is receiving the whole `Response` object although from the variable name, we assume you were expecting a `Heroes` object. (Typescript will catch that kind of error if you set the type to something other than `any`)

Now when you log `result`, it logs the Result object you just received. Which includes the body holding your stringified object.

`result[0]` is empty because `result` isn't an array.

I think you want:

```
service.getGoogle().subscribe((result: any) => {
    heroes = JSON.parse(result._body)

    // heroes is now an array you started with
    // heroes[0] == {"name":"aditya"}
    // heroes[1] == {"name":"xyz"}
```

Comment: Actually, I am passing hard coded response here, which is JSON.So I have created a JSON array.After creating it I pass it as a response which serves my mock request.And then want to display this response in the console and test this.

Comment: You are displaying your response in the console: `Response{_body: '[{"name":"aditya"},{"name":"xyz"}]', status: null, ok: false, statusText: null, headers: null, type: null, url: null}`

Comment: I want to display "name":"aditya" as the first element of the array, How would I do this?

Comment: Did you try parsing the JSON with `JSON.parse(result._body)`?

Comment: yes, it displays `[Object{name: 'aditya'}, Object{name: 'xyz'}]`

Comment: It is a JSON array now.I tested it with `expect(data[0]).toEqual({"name":"aditya"})`, it passed!